# Django: How to annotate M2M or OneToMany fields using a SubQuery?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have `Order` objects and `OrderOperation` objects that represent an action on a Order (creation, modification, cancellation).

Conceptually, an order has 1 to many order operations. Each time there is an operation on the order, the total is computed in this operation. Which means when I need to find an attribute of an order, I just get the last order operation attribute instead, using a Subquery.

### **The simplified code**

```
class OrderOperation(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    total = DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

class Order(models.Model)
    # ...

class OrderQuerySet(query.Queryset):

    @staticmethod
    def _last_oo(field):
        return Subquery(OrderOperation.objects
                        .filter(order_id=OuterRef("pk"))
                        .order_by('-id')
                        .values(field)
                        [:1])

    def annotated_total(self):
        return self.annotate(oo_total=self._last_oo('total'))
```

This way, I can run `my_order_total = Order.objects.annotated_total()[0].oo_total`. It works great.

### **The issue**

Computing total is easy as it's a simple value. However, when there is a M2M or OneToMany field, this method does not work. For example, using the example above, let's add this field:

```
class OrderOperation(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    total = DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    ordered_articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article,through='orders.OrderedArticle')
```

Writing something like the following does NOT work as it returns only 1 foreign key (not a list of all the FKs):

```
def annotated_ordered_articles(self):
    return self.annotate(oo_ordered_articles=self._last_oo('ordered_articles'))
```

### **The purpose**

The whole purpose is to allow a user to search among all orders, providing a list or articles in input. For example: "Please find all orders containing at least article 42 or article 43", or "Please find all orders containing exactly article 42 and 43", etc.

If I could get something like:

```
>>> Order.objects.annotated_ordered_articles()[0].oo_ordered_articles
<ArticleQuerySet [<Article: Article42>, <Article: Article43>]>
```

or even:

```
>>> Order.objects.annotated_ordered_articles()[0].oo_ordered_articles
[42,43]
```

That would solve my issue.

### **My current idea**

- Maybe something like [`ArrayAgg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) (I'm using pgSQL) could do the trick, but I'm not sure to understand how to use it in my case.
- Maybe this has to do with `values()` method that seems to not be intended to handle M2M and 1TM relations as stated in the doc:

> values() and values_list() are both intended as optimizations for a
>   specific use case: retrieving a subset of data without the overhead of
>   creating a model instance. This metaphor falls apart when dealing with
>   many-to-many and other multivalued relations (such as the one-to-many
>   relation of a reverse foreign key) because the “one row, one object”
>   assumption doesn’t hold.

Comment: What is your desired behavior?

Comment: @GwynBleidD question updated with "The purpose" section.

Comment: Should it get them only from last `OrderOperation`?

Comment: @GwynBleidD yes. The behaviour should be similar to `total`. Except that `total` returns a simple Decimal value in `OrderOperation`, while `ordered_articles` is a manager for many to many fields, so it's more complicated to handle I guess :)

Answer (score 7):

`ArrayAgg` will be great if you want to fetch only one variable (ie. name) from all articles. If you need more, there is a better option for that:

## `prefetch_related`

Instead, you can prefetch for each `Order`, latest `OrderOperation` as a whole object. This adds the ability to easily get any field from `OrderOperation` without extra magic.

The only caveat with that is that you will always get a list with one operation or an empty list when there are no operations for selected order.

To do that, you should use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) queryset model together with [`Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) and custom query for `OrderOperation`. Example:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F, Prefetch

last_order_operation_qs = OrderOperation.objects.annotate(
    lop_pk=Max('order__orderoperation__pk')
).filter(pk=F('lop_pk'))

orders = Order.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('orderoperation_set', queryset=last_order_operation_qs, to_attr='last_operation')
)
```

Then you can just use `order.last_operation[0].ordered_articles` to get all ordered articles for particular order. You can add `prefetch_related('ordered_articles')` to first queryset to have improved performance and less queries on database.

Comment: Note that this is actually an improvement from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54828011/1783237) to your previous question, but it does not allow filtering on anything prefetched using `to_attr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, so helpful.. Since my purpose is to get orders, given a list of articles as input, what do you think of replacing the "prefetch part" of your answer by this solution: `order_pks = last_order_operation_qs.filter(ordered_articles__in=[1,4]).select_related('order').values('order__pk')` then `Order.objects.filter(pk__in=order_pks)`?

Answer (score 5):

To my surprise, your idea with `ArrayAgg` is right on the money. I didn't know there was a way to annotate with an array (and I believe there still isn't for backends other than Postgres).

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.general import ArrayAgg

qs = Order.objects.annotate(oo_articles=ArrayAgg(
            'order_operation__ordered_articles__id',
            'DISTINCT'))
```

You can then filter the resulting queryset using the [ArrayField lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield):

```
# Articles that contain the specified array
qs.filter(oo_articles__contains=[42,43])
# Articles that are identical to the specified array
qs.filter(oo_articles=[42,43,44])
# Articles that are contained in the specified array
qs.filter(oo_articles__contained_by=[41,42,43,44,45])
# Articles that have at least one element in common
# with the specified array
qs.filter(oo_articles__overlap=[41,42])
```

`'DISTINCT'` is needed only if the operation may contain duplicate articles.

You may need to tweak the exact name of the field passed to the `ArrayAgg` function. For subsequent filtering to work, you may also need to cast id fields in the `ArrayAgg` to `int` as otherwise Django casts the id array to `::serial[]`, and my Postgres complained about `type "serial[]" does not exist`:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.array import ArrayField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

ArrayAgg(Cast('order_operation__ordered_articles__id', IntegerField()))
# OR
Cast(ArrayAgg('order_operation__ordered_articles__id'), ArrayField(IntegerField()))
```

Looking at your posted code more closely, you'll also have to filter on the one `OrderOperation` you are interested in; the query above looks at all operations for the relevant order.

Comment: Perfect! I got distinct values with the latest Django by using `ArrayAgg(field_name, distinct=True)`. Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg).